# Delete Symbolic Link in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcut

i want to delete some symbolic Links (Folder). I tried

```
(Get-Item "C:\Users\MIKROEG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\*.*").Delete()
```

or

```
[string]$Nutzerpfad = "$env:APPDATA"
[string]$Destination = "$Nutzerpfad\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\*.*"
[System.IO.Directory]::Delete($Destination, $true)
```

or

```
cmd /s rmdir C:\Users\MIKROEG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\Test2
```

or

```
$alleordneranzeigen=Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Directory
foreach($ordner in $alleordneranzeigen)
{ Remove-Item -Path $ordner.FullName
}
```

but nothing works.
The last one wants to delete recurse.

Can anyone help me?

[INK][1]

Comment: Refer to https://www.computerhope.com/mklink.htm for further clarification. cmd /s rmdir.... should do the trick if you are trying to delete a junction point.

Comment: rmdir "C:\Users\MIKROEG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\Test2" wants also delete recurse :(

Comment: Are you trying to delete the files inside of the target directory (using mklink /d) or just the directory link (rmdir) ?

Comment: I created a test symbolic link in "C:\Users\MIKROEG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\Test2" The Folder test2 is saved on my Desktop and have some test files. I only want delete the symbolic link "C:\Users\MIKROEG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\Test2" and not the Desktop Folder.

Answer (score 3):

A directory symbolic link, typically created using `mklink /D mysymlink C:\myfiles\somefile` at the command line, can be removed like a directory using

`rd <mysymlink>`

(This is equivalent to the long form of the command, `rmdir <mysymlink>`. You did in fact try `rmdir` but this would have failed due to the space character in your unquoted path:
`cmd /s rmdir C:\Users\MIKROEG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\Test2` .)

You may demonstrate this by making a backup copy of the directory in File Explorer, and using the `rd` command on your directory symlink. You will see that the symlink is removed, and the original directory and its contents are still present.

**Warning about trying other ways:** a directory symbolic link cannot be deleted like a **file** at the command line, using `del`. Doing so deletes **the files in the directory!**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check carefully what you are deleting:

```
# Only Show: SymbolicLink
(Get-ChildItem . -Force -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LinkType -eq "SymbolicLink" -and $_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint" }) | Select FullName, LinkType, Target

# WARNING: Delete those
(Get-ChildItem . -Force -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LinkType -eq "SymbolicLink" -and $_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint" }) | Select $_.FullName | | Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 7 can delete symlinks with "del" or "remove-item".  Elevated prompt to create it, all parameters are named position.  -Target would be an alias for -value

```
new-item -ItemType SymbolicLink -name symlink -value c:\users\js\foo
```

```
del symlink
```

In powershell 5.1, you can use the delete method of the DirectoryInfo item.  Caution, using get-childitem instead would delete all the files inside the folder!

```
get-item symlink | % delete
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to **properly** delete symbolic links using

> mklink /d

you can just delete the symbolic link inside of windows explorer. This way you do not even need to bother using powershell.

**HOWEVER:**

If you are looking to delete the link with powershell DO NOT use

> rmdir

Instead target the designated folder like this:

> cmd /c rmdir .\Target

Comment: PS H:\> cmd /c rmdir "C:\Users\MIKROEG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\Test2"
cmd : Zugriff verweigert
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ cmd /c rmdir "C:\Users\MIKROEG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Netw ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Zugriff verweigert:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I have admin rights...

Comment: What windows version do you currently have installed?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 1809

Comment: cmd mklink /d "C:\Users\MIKROEG\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\Test2" doesn't work...

Comment: That's fairly odd, unfortunately I am not sure how else to help you. Please check out this forum: https://superuser.com/questions/167076/how-can-i-delete-a-symbolic-link it suggests more alternatives. If you found that I was helpful, i'd appreciate if you can state that my answers were helpful using the arrow. Noticed you are new. Welcome to the community and best of luck

Comment: Can't I modify the Remove Item command so that it won't delete recursively? Surely it must be possible to delete a folder shortcut? :(

Comment: Yes you should be able to but for some reason something is getting into the way from letting you do so. Where is the relative path of your folder and files included?

Comment: The symbolic Link has the path C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\Test2.Ink
and the Folder is C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Test2

Actually the Desktop Folder has only test files for try and fail...

Comment: okay Maybe i have a "solution". If i move the link to Folder1 into Folder 2 and delete Folder 2 recursively. The Folder 2 with the link to Folder 1 is gone but Folder 1 is still there. but Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Interesting, probably not the best way to go about it as your having to reposition folders for no reason. You said the desktop folder has only files for try and file. What are the 2 other folders? You want to delete all of them?

Comment: Yeah, it's not the prettiest code, but it works. The folder and shortcut (to dekstop folder) under Network Shortcuts is a trial setup for a shortcut to a network drive. No, it is really a shortcut, it is not connected. Finally, I want to delete the shortcut without the files on the network drive. I tried it with my "solution" and the correct variables and it work too. But I would also like to solve it more beautifully